# Raspberry Pi Java

Tags: pi-3, java

If you have a raspberry pi:

Okay, so I am trying to run jar files on my raspberry pi. I recently made a twitter bot and want to run it 24/7 on there. However when I run "java -jar MyTwitterBot.jar" it comes up with the exception "Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile MyTwitterBot.jar"... I really don't understand what's wrong with this. I really just want it fixed. How can the jar file be corrupted if I don't even touch it or anything? If anyone has a solution or can offer some help, please hit me up, thanks!

Comment: is the Java version used to compile the code the same as the version used to run it. Was the code compiled for the Pi. Was the jar compiled for a 64bit machine?

Comment: It was compiled on my macbook pro using IntelliJ IDEA. I used 1.8 and the Pi has 1.8.

Comment: Can you try running in on your mac?  Does it work?  See also this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559072/corrupt-jar-file

Comment: If there's JNI stuff in there somewhere it will be a problem; that has to be compiled for/on the Pi.